# Wrap localForage setItem calls in Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, promise, localforage

I want to refresh my indexeddb store with new data after a successful login. After the data refresh is complete, I want to redirect to the landing page. My problem is that I have 1000+ calls to setItem and they aren't finishing.

```
var app = {
Login: function () {
    WebService.Login($("#username").val(), $("#password").val())
        .then(function () {
            // TODO: refresh data and then redirect...
            UpdateData().then(function() {
                window.location.href = '/Home';
            });

        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("error logging in");
        });

},
UpdateData: function () {

    return fetch('/api/Customer').then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        var customerStore = localforage.createInstance({ name: "customers" });
        // Refresh data
        customerStore.clear().then(function () {
            data.forEach(function (c) {
                // How do I know when all setItem calls are complete??
                customerStore.setItem(String(c.CustomerID), c);
            });
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log("Data error", err);
    });
}

}
```

I'm still relatively new to promises but there must be a way I can get all of the setItem calls into a Promise.all() that I can return. How can I do this?

Comment: Don't use `forEach`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need something like this:

```
return fetch("/api/Customer")
.then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
})
.then(function(data) {
    var customerStore = localforage.createInstance({ name: "customers" });
    // Refresh data
    return customerStore.clear().then(function() {
        return Promise.all(
            data.map(function(c) {
                return customerStore.setItem(String(c.CustomerID), c);
            })
        );
    });
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log("Data error", err);
});
```

`data.map` will return an array of promises and then we also return the aggregate promise (from `Promise.all`).

You should also keep a reference of the `customerStore` for later use.
Also, if the amount of data is huge, you  might want to use [localForage-setItems](https://github.com/localForage/localForage-setItems) to make the operation a bit more performant (but try to avoid a possible premature optimization).